# Inner product of two mapping function in a Kernal

Tags: inner-products

I need to get the inner product of these two functions. $
\langle\psi(x),\psi(x^\prime)\rangle$

$\psi(x) = (\mathbf{1^x;0^{N-x}})$ where  $\mathbf{1^x}$ is the vector in $\mathbb{R}^x$ with all the elements equal to 1, and $\mathbf{0^{N-x}}$ is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{N-x}$

First of all what does the semi-colon in the middle mean?

I know the answer is $min\{x,x\prime\}$ but I don't understand how to reach this point. Can someone please explain it to me.